# Container Monitoring in Azure Monitor without Log Analytics Agent

Tags: azure, monitoring, azure-monitoring, azure-log-analytics-workspace

We have some Docker containers running on RHEL 8 Azure VM. I want to get the metrics from the container to Log Analytics Workspace. (As per this document we have to install the Log Analytics Agent to get the container metrics)

My Question: Can we get the container metrics without installing Log Analytics Agent only with Azure Monitor agent on VM As Log Analytics Agent is soon going to be deprecated?

Document link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/containers/containers
Msft document suggestion :
Install and use Docker with a Log Analytics agent. Based on your operating system and Docker orchestrator, you can use the following methods to configure your agent.

For standalone hosts:
On supported Linux operating systems, install and run Docker and then install and configure the Log Analytics agent for Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can we get the container metrics without installing Log Analytics Agent only with Azure Monitor agent on VM As Log Analytics Agent is soon going to be deprecated?
```

AFAIK currently the Azure Monitor agent by itself is **unable** to gather metrics from **a standalone** Docker container operating on a RHEL 8 Azure VM.

```
As per this document we have to install the Log Analytics Agent to get the container metrics
```

- yes, as per the document you mentioned you can use log analytics agent. **The Log Analytics agent will be deprecated by August 2024**, and users are encouraged to migrate to the Azure Monitor agent before then.
- You can use Azure Monitor logs to monitor containers and Container insights logs to query logs. Nevertheless, you must install the Log Analytics agent on the VM if you wish to gather more specific metrics from your containers, such as CPU or memory consumption.
- You must continue using the Log Analytics Agent for Linux to gather container metrics in accordance with the instructions in the legacy documentation if you are unable to switch to a supported container orchestration system.

As it is not possible in your standalone case i am just suggesting that as mentioned in your document you can use that log analytics agent and then you can [migrate to azure monitor agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-migration).

Refer this MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/azure-monitor-agent-migration) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As we are initiate stages to implement the monitoring in our system. I am worried after deprecated the Log Analysis Agent what will happen.? Is Microsoft going to provide this functionality in Azure Monitor Agent?

Comment: We can't say it exactly without getting any confirmation from Microsoft. AFAIK Microsoft is planning to provide the functionality of the Log Analytics agent in the Azure Monitor agent before deprecating the Log Analytics agent. Azure Monitor agent is already able to gather a wide variety of metrics, logs, and events. Microsoft is also aiming to expand the Azure Monitor agent's support for other metrics and logs, including container metrics. Hence, compared to the Log Analytics agent, you may anticipate that the Azure Monitor agent will be able to offer comparable or enhanced features.